# Regex: yaml finding match

Tags: regex, yaml

I am trying to get a match in regex for all root yaml entries with their values. So only with entries with a value are considered (not matching any nested entries). I have been messing around with it but to no avail. thanks!

so with this example:

```html
metadata:
  url: "https://www.google.com"
booleanvalue: 'false'
tls:
  host:
    google_net: "google.net"
  secret:
    big_secert_net: "cert"
API_HOST: 'https://api.test.com'
DOMAIN: 'api.domain'
METRIC_ENVIRONMENT: 'test'
```

Regex would return this match:

```html
booleanvalue: 'false'
API_HOST: 'https://api.test.com'
DOMAIN: 'api.domain'
METRIC_ENVIRONMENT: 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E '^[^\r\n]+:[^\S\r\n]+[^[{\r\n][^\r\n]*$' test.yaml
```

What I'm doing:

- `^[^\r\n]+:` Match key at the beginning of the line
- `[^\S\r\n]+` Match inline whitespace (some implementations provide `\h` for this). There must be at least one whitespace characters after the colon.
- `[^[{\r\n][^\r\n]*$` Match the content. Ensure it starts with something that is not `[` or `{` on the same line (those would start nested YAML objects). Then, match everything until the end of the line.